# Change the color of a table rows with a condition

Tags: excel, vba, rows, rgb, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to write a VBA in order to change the color (between two different ones) of a table row if the content of a cell is different from the previous.
The row n. 3 must have this color: RGB(221, 245, 253), while the other color is white.
I'm not able to figure out which would be the logic code and how to change the background color of the cells without changing the font color.

```
Public Sub Overview()

Dim Ovtask As String
Dim Ovn, Ovi As Integer

Ovn = Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Range("B3:C3").Font.Color = RGB(221, 245, 253)
For Ovi = 3 To Ovn + 1
Ovtask = Range("B" & Ovi)
    If Range("B" & Ovi + 1) = Ovtask Then
        Range("B" & Ovi + 1 & ":" & "C" & Ovi + 1).Font.Color = Range("B" & Ovi & ":" & "C" & Ovi).Font.Color
        Else
        Range("B" & Ovi + 1 & ":" & "C" & Ovi + 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
Next Ovi
End Sub
```

In the linked image you can see what would be the desired result
[image]

Comment: `Range.Interior.Color`?

Comment: Also, note that you can get the alternating colors using Conditional Formatting, and you don't need VBA.

Comment: That's correct, but the result it's not what I aim to: for sure there is a mistake in the code, and the result color is black and not white

Comment: @user3561813 I've tried with no success. My difficult in the conditional formatting is how to assign the color, because when the condition is true the color is kept, when the condition is false must change, in relation to the color of the previous row. For example: row1 starts with blue, row2 condition false->change the color to white, row3 condition false->change the color to blue, row4 condition true->keep the color blue, row5 condition false->change the color to white, row6 condition true->keep the color white

Answer (score 0):

As BigBen states in the comments, to set the color of a cell, you use `Interior.Color`. I thought about conditional formatting, but I think you are right, it's not possible in this case.

The logic you use in your code is flawed: Once it sets a row to white, it will never set any row to blue: Either the next row is equal, then you set it to white because the current row is white, or it is not equal, then you set it to white anyhow.

Have a look to the following code snippet: I declare a boolean variable `UseHighlightColor` that keeps track if the current row needs to be colored blue or not and sets the `Interior.Color` accordingly. Some remarks to the color:
  - white is `RGB(255, 255, 255)`. `RGB(0, 0, 0)` results in black.
  - there is a predefined constant `vbWhite` you could use.
  - To set the cells transparent instead of white, you can use `ColorIndex = xlNone`.

And a remark to your code: You are using `Range` unqualified, so VBA automatically refers to the ActiveSheet (the sheet that has currently the focus). This is not always the sheet you work with. In my example, I have written `With ActiveSheet`, but you can easily change this so that the code uses the sheet you want, eg `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`. Inside the `With`, I use the syntax `.Range` (with leading `.`), this tells VBA to use the object (sheet) defined in the `With`-clause. Don't rely on ActiveSheet (and don't use `Activate`).

```
With ActiveSheet
    Ovn = .Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Dim useHighLightColor As Boolean
    useHighLightColor = True

    For Ovi = 3 To Ovn + 1
        Dim currentCell As Range
        Set currentCell = .Range("B" & Ovi)
        If useHighLightColor Then
            currentCell.Resize(1, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 245, 253)
        Else
            ' curentCell.Resize(1, 2).Interior.Color = vbWhite
            currentCell.Resize(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If

        If currentCell <> currentCell.Offset(1, 0) Then
            ' Switch color
            useHighLightColor = Not useHighLightColor
        End If
    Next Ovi
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious suggestions. I'll try to learn what you proposed, I've applied your code but there's something to adjust because the penultimate row is blue instead of white.

Comment: I reviewed my attempts and now the script works perfectly! (it was my fault)